# where should the size values be place?

Tags: flutter, dart, structure

I am making the length and width values with the help of Mediaquery to be a responsive design. Where should I put these values ? in core/constants/ ? is there any project I can take an example of to find out this kind of thing or document.

```
├───core
│   ├───constants
│   │   ├───app
│   │   ├───color
│   │   └───textstyle
│   ├───extension
│   └───init
│       └───translations
├───product
│   ├───error
│   ├───navigator
│   │   └───guard
│   └───widget
│       ├───appbar
│       ├───button
│       └───textfield
├───providers
└───view
    ├───authenticate
    │   ├───login
    │   │   ├───model
    │   │   ├───service
    │   │   ├───view
    │   │   └───viewmodel
    │   ├───onboard
    │   │   ├───model
    │   │   ├───view
    │   │   └───widget
    │   ├───register
    │   │   ├───model
    │   │   ├───service
    │   │   └───view
    │   └───reset_password_view.dart
    │       └───view
    ├───home
    │   ├───home
    │   │   └───view
    │   ├───menu
    │   │   └───view
    │   ├───models
    │   ├───more
    │   │   └───view
    │   ├───offers
    │   │   └───view
    │   └───profile
    │       └───view
    ├───welcome
    │   └───view
    └───_product
        └───_widgets
            ├───card
            ├───listtile
            └───safearea
```

- 

```
extension MediaQueryExtension on BuildContext {
  double dynamicWidth(double val) => MediaQuery.of(this).size.width * val;
  double dynamicHeight(double val) => MediaQuery.of(this).size.height * val;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no written rule about the question you ask.
It usually depends on developers/company preferences.

But since the extension can be used project wide, the most reasonable place for it would be core/extensions.

I would not place it inside constants since it's not a constant values.